# Using master page and web forms in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

When using a master page, is there anyway i can see what web form is currently loaded or being loaded in the master page, so before this line:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

i would like to see/get the web form that's going to be loaded in the master page, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have access to the `Page` property from the master page.

To see this in action, from the default Visual Studio template of an ASP.NET web application (which comes with a master page), dump this in the master where the `h1` title is:

```
My ASP.NET Application <%= Page.GetType().Name %>
```

It will show up in the browser as `My ASP.NET Application default_aspx` or whatever page you're on.

Comment: Anytime. FYI: There's also a `Page` property on user controls which works the same way, so from the opposite end of the lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have access to the page being loaded, but you can create a public property on the master page called eg `currentPage` and set it on the `Page_Load` of the page itself to the value you want. This way you can check it on the Site.Master code:

```
// on the Site.Master.cs
public string CurrentPage;


// on the page, inside the Page_Load event
((Site)this.Master).CurrentPage = 'My page';


// on the Site.Master
<%
if (CurrentPage == "My page")
{
    %>My page is loaded.<%
}
else
{
    %>Another page is loaded.<%
}
```

Comment: Will this work if i want to see the page to be loaded before its loaded?

Comment: This will work because when the aspx code from the master is executed, the page has already been loaded. Look for "webforms load order" and you can have a better understanding of what is going on when you use a master page.